# Select with condition on function value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a beginner's question to SQL queries: How do I select the rows of a table satisfying a condition given in form of function of the columns? More specifically, I have a table with a string 'topic', which actually is empty or contains a integer string and I like to do something like (in an efficient maner)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Convert(int,'topic') BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

How can this be done? (The above syntax seems to be wrong...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use implicit casting

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE topic BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

or explicit

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE cast(topic as signed) BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Comment: Perfect, that does it :-) !

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's "silent" conversion facility.  This converts the leading digits of a string to a number in a numeric context.  If there are no such numbers, then 0 is returned.

So, for your example, you can just do:

```
where topic + 0 between 1 and 10
```

If the string has no leading digits, this returns false.